# How to Delete a Vaex df from memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, vaex

I am not able to find out how to delete all the reduntant vaex df from memory.

For a pandas dataframe I am using:

```
def delete_df():
    dflist=[var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var),pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
    del [[dflist]]
    gc.collect()
```

If you could help me with how to delete vaex dataframe,that would be great

Thanks

Comment: looking for this...! Any useful way found ?

Comment: currently solved with multiprocessing